# Using camera on background (multitasking?) on ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to make app as my master thesis on ios 7 but I need to know if could run camera on background. I need to record video after user press home button (it should be traffic cam to car while user uses another app eg. navigation). I know it was not possilbe in ios 6 but I know that ios 7 has better support for background tasks... Is it please possible? I would be grateful for every answer. Thank you

Comment: I hope not. Checked the docs?

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of long-running tasks permitted in the background in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1).

Camera access is not one of them. You will need to have your app in the foreground to use the camera.

Comment: It's good that apple doesn't allow because it increases risk of apps capturing your moments from background without making you notice. Thus risk to privacy.